# Finding Patterns in a Numpy Array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to find patterns in a `numpy` `array`, called `values`. I'd like to return the starting index position of the pattern. I know I could iterative over each element and check whether that element and the next one match the pattern, but over a large dataset that is incredibly inefficient and am looking for a better alternative.

I've got a working solution using `np.where` for searching for a single value, but I can't get it to work with finding a pattern or two numbers.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array([0,1,2,1,2,4,5,6,1,2,1])
searchval = [1,2]
print  np.where(values == searchval)[0]
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Expected Output:

```
[1, 3, 8]
```

Comment: Maybe Rolling Hashes can help. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couldn't you simply use `np.where` (assuming this is the optimal way to find an element) and then only check pattens which satisfy the first condition.

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array([0,1,2,1,2,4,5,6,1,2,1])
searchval = [1,2]
N = len(searchval)
possibles = np.where(values == searchval[0])[0]

solns = []
for p in possibles:
    check = values[p:p+N]
    if np.all(check == searchval):
        solns.append(p)

print(solns)
```

Comment: If the input is random (there are a few repeat in values) this solution will be fast

Answer (score 7):

Here's a straight forward approach to using where.  Start with a logical expression that finds the matches:

```
In [670]: values = np.array([0,1,2,1,2,4,5,6,1,2,1])
     ...: searchval = [1,2]
     ...: 
In [671]: (values[:-1]==searchval[0]) & (values[1:]==searchval[1])
Out[671]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
In [672]: np.where(_)
Out[672]: (array([1, 3, 8], dtype=int32),)
```

That could be generalized into a loop that operates on multiple `searchval`.  Getting the slice range correct will take some fiddling.  The `roll` suggested in another answer might be easier, but I suspect a bit slower.

As long as `searchval` is small compared to `values` this general approach should be efficient.  There is a `np.in1d` that does this sort of match, but with a `or` test.  So it isn't applicable.  But it too uses this iterative approach is the `searchval` list is small enough.

### Generalized slicing

```
In [716]: values
Out[716]: array([0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1])
In [717]: searchvals=[1,2,1]
In [718]: idx = [np.s_[i:m-n+1+i] for i in range(n)]
In [719]: idx
Out[719]: [slice(0, 9, None), slice(1, 10, None), slice(2, 11, None)]
In [720]: [values[idx[i]] == searchvals[i] for i in range(n)]
Out[720]: 
[array([False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool),
 array([False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool),
 array([False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)]
In [721]: np.all(_, axis=0)
Out[721]: array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
In [722]: np.where(_)
Out[722]: (array([1, 8], dtype=int32),)
```

I used the intermediate `np.s_` to look at the slices and make sure they look reasonable.

### as_strided

An advanced trick would be to use `as_strided` to construct the 'rolled' array and perform a 2d `==` test on that.  `as_strided` is neat but tricky.  To use it correctly you have to understand strides, and get the shape correct.

```
In [740]: m,n = len(values), len(searchvals)
In [741]: values.shape
Out[741]: (11,)
In [742]: values.strides
Out[742]: (4,)
In [743]: 
In [743]: M = as_strided(values, shape=(n,m-n+1),strides=(4,4))
In [744]: M
Out[744]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1],
       [1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1]])
In [745]: M == np.array(searchvals)[:,None]
Out[745]: 
array([[False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
In [746]: np.where(np.all(_,axis=0))
Out[746]: (array([1, 8], dtype=int32),)
```

Comment: Good idea on slicing, should be pretty efficient for decent sized patterns.

Comment: Can you use the as_strided  on a matrix?

Answer (score 3):

I think this does the job:

```
np.where((values == 1) & (np.roll(values,-1) == 2))[0]
```

Comment: Since we have a great collection of soutions I was currious about the run times and found the hpaulij solutions are around 2 times faster on pretty long random arrays (e.g. 1 mil entries) compared to the simple roll. The solution by Ed Smith is about 100 times slower and the one by betontalpfa another 100 times. Number of entries and hits changes the numbers quite a bit but not the overall ranking.

Answer (score 2):

If the input is random Ed Smith solution is faster. But if you has a few set of available values this hash-solution can help:

```
"""
Can be replaced with any revertable hash
"""
def my_hash(rem, h, add):
    return rem^h^add

"""
Imput
"""
values = np.array([0,1,2,1,2,4,5,6,1,2,1])
searchval = [1,2]


"""
Prepare
"""
sh = 0
vh = 0
ls = len(searchval)
lv = len(values)

for i in range(0, len(searchval)):
    vh = my_hash(0, vh, values[i])
    sh = my_hash(0, sh, searchval[i])

"""
Find matches
"""
for i in range(0, lv-ls):
    if sh == vh:
        eq = True
        for j in range(0, ls):
            if values[i+j] != searchval[j]:
                eq = False
                break
        if eq:
            print i
    vh = my_hash(values[i], vh, values[i+ls])
```

Answer (score 2):

Compact straitforward solution will be a "legal" variant of as_strided solution. Others have mentioned `np.roll`.
But here is an universal solution with the only circle (132 µs).

```
seq = np.array([0,1,2,1,2,4,5,6,1,2,1])
patt = np.array([1,2])

Seq = np.vstack([np.roll(seq, shift) for shift in -np.arange(len(patt))]).T
where(all(Seq == patt, axis=1))[0]
```

The another option for sequences with small integers will be converting to string.
It is faster per near 6 times (20 µs).
For small positive integers only!

```
import re

def to_string(arr):
    return ''.join(map(chr, arr))

array([m.start() for m in re.finditer(to_string(patt), to_string(seq))])
```