# Numpy: Search for an array A with same pattern in a larger array B

Tags: numpy

I have two 1D numpy array A(small) and B(large)

```
A=np.array([6,7,8,9,10])

B=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,10])
```

I want to check if we have elements of the array A in the same order being detected in the array B. 
Get the index value of array B from where the we detect the starting of array A

```
Index Value returned = 6
```

Do we have any inbuilt numpy function to perform such an operation?

Comment: Just to check - do you mean if it's an exact subarray... eg: if `B = [..., 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 10]` - would that be a match or not?

Comment: @JonClements Yes, you got it right. That's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice solution.

Given by @EdSmith in [Finding Patterns in a Numpy Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491979/finding-patterns-in-a-numpy-array)

In short this is the process

- Short the length of array being searched for.(My example A)
- Check through entire length of the array being searched in(My example B), using np.where and np.all

This is not my code but the code that can be found in the about link, Simple and easy. I'll just alter it a bit to fit my example above Hope it helps someone :)

Thanks to @EdSmith

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([6,7,8,9,10])

B=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,10])

N = len(A)
possibles = np.where(B == A[0])[0]

solns = []
for p in possibles:
    check = B[p:p+N]
if np.all(check == A):
    solns.append(p)

print(solns)
```

Ouput

```
[6]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered this problem sometimes.I think the fastest way especially for big numpy arrays would be to convert them to strings and then do it.
Here is the code I use:

```
b=np.array([6,7,8,9,10])    
a=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,10])
a.tostring().index(b.tostring())//a.itemsize
```

Comment: Nice, temporary fix. For a small number of elements in an array. I would be dealing with huge number of elements in an array. I doubt this would be an efficient way to use then, by looking at the amount of data that needs to be converted to string and store in virtual memory first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([6,7,8,9,10])
B=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,10])
r = np.ones_like(B)
for x in range(len(A)):r*=np.roll((B==A[x]),-x)
#first index, answer: /6/ 
print(np.where(r)[0][0])
```