# Counting ocurrences of specific True/False ordering in Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pattern-matching

I have a Numpy Array of True and False values like:

```
test = np.array([False, False, False, True, False, True, False, True, False,False, False, False, True, True, False, True])
```

I would like to know the number of times the following pattern (False, True, False) happens in the array. In the test above it will be 4. This is not the only pattern, but I assume that when I understand this code I can probably also make the others.

Of course, I can loop over the array. If the first value is equal, compare the next and otherwise go to the next value in the loop. Like this:

```
totalTimes=0
def swapToBegin(x):
    if(x>=len(test)):
        x-=len(test)
    return(x)
for i in range(len(test)):
    if(test[i]==False):
        if(test[swapToBegin(i+1)]==True):
            if test[swapToBegin(i+2)]==False:
                totalTimes += 1
```

However, since I need to do this many times, this code will be very slow. Little improvements can be made, since this was made very quickly to show what I need. But there must be a better solution.

Is there a better way to search for a pattern in an array? It does not need to combine the end and beginning of the array, since I would be able to this afterwards. But if it can be included it would be nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding Patterns in a Numpy Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491979/finding-patterns-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Do you need to match overlapping results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given any details on how large `test` is, so for benchmarks of the methods I've used it has 1000 elements.  The next important part is to actually profile the code.  You can't say it's slow (or fast) until there are hard numbers to back it up. Your code runs in around 1.49ms on my computer.

You can often get improvements with numpy by removing python loops and replacing them with numpy functions.
So, rather than testing each element individually (lots of `if` conditions could slow things down) I've put it all into one array comparison, then used `all` to check that every element matches.

```
check = array([False, True, False])
sum([(test[i:i+3]==check).all() for i in range(len(test) - 2)])
```

Profiling this shows it running in 1.91ms.

That's actually a step backwards.  So, what could be causing the slowdown?  Well, array access using `[]` creates a new array object which could be part of it.  A better approach may be to create one large array with the offsets, then use broadcasting to do the comparison.

```
sum((c_[test[:-2], test[1:-1], test[2:]] == check).all(1))
```

This time `check` is compared with each row of the array `c_[test[:-2], test[1:-1], test[2:]]`.  The axis argument (1) of `all` is used to only count rows that every element matches.  This runs in 40.1us.  That's a huge improvement.

Of course, creating the array to broadcast is going to have a large cost in terms of copying elements over.  Why not do the comparisons directly?

```
sum(all([test[i:len(test)-2+i]==v for i, v in enumerate(check)], 0))
```

This runs in 18.7us.

The last idea to speed things up is using `as_strided`.  This is an advanced trick to alter the strides of an array to get the offset array without copying any data.  It's usually not worth the effort, but I'm including it here just for fun.

```
sum((np.lib.index_tricks.as_strided(test, (len(test) - len(check) + 1, len(check)), test.strides + (1, )) == check).all(1))
```

This also runs in around 40us.  So, the extra effort doesn't add anything in this case.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped speeding up my code! (the third approach) However, checking the 2 overlay options takes as long as checking all 94 other options (test has length 96). How would you approach these? Checking element by element (so 2*3=6 comparisons) is not as fast as I'd hoped.

+ (test[-2]==check[:2]).all()*(test[1]==check[2]) + (test[-1]==check[0])*(test[:2]==check[1:]).all()

This takes as long as the first part..., and I don't understand what's so slow about it. The Profiler doesn't give me an insight either.

Comment: With arrays of length 96 most of the overhead is probably in python rather than numy, that would be why it's just as fast to check 96 items as 2.  If you can alter how `test` is created and duplicate the first two elements at the end that would give you the speedup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array containing [False, True, False] and search for this instead.

```
searchfor = np.array([False, True, False])
```

Comment: Sorry if I am mistaken, but you only appear to show how to make an array to search for, but not how to actually search for it.