# Finding 2D boolean patterns in larger boolean tensors/arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am looking for a way to find a 2D pattern in a MxNxR tensor/array with pytorch or numpy.
For instance, to see if a dictionary of tensor of boolean pattern (e.g. {6x6 : freq}) exist in a larger boolean tensor (e.g. 3x256x256).

Then I want to update my patterns and frequencies of the dictionary.

I was hoping that there was a pytorchi way of doing it, instead of having loops over it, or have an optimized loop for doing it.

As far as I know, torch.where works when we have a scalar value. I’m not sure how should I do, if I have a tensor of 6x6 instead of a value.
I looked into [Finding Patterns in a Numpy Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491979/finding-patterns-in-a-numpy-array) , but I don't think that it's feasible to follow it for a 2D pattern.

Comment: what have you tried? post a minimal example

Comment: I have tried torch.where, and equals, but they only work for scalar values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking maybe you can pull this off using convolutions. Let's imagine you have an input made up of `0` and `1`. Here we will take a minimal example with an u=input of `3x3` and a `2x2` pattern:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([[1., 0., 0.],
                      [0., 1., 0.],
                      [1., 0., 0.]])
```

And the pattern would be:

```
>>> pattern = torch.tensor([[1., 0.],
                            [0., 1.]])
```

Here the pattern can be found in the upper left corner of the input.

We perform a convolution with [`nn.functional.conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.conv2d.html) with `1 - pattern` as the kernel.

```
>>> img, mask = x[None, None], pattern[None, None]
>>> M = F.conv2d(img, 1 - mask)
tensor([[[[0., 1.],
          [2., 0.]]]])
```

There is a match if and only if the result is equal to the number of `1`s in the pattern:

```
>>> M == mask.sum(dim=(2,3)))
tensor([[[[ True, False],
          [False, False]]]])
```

You can deduce the frequencies from this final boolean mask. You can extend this method to multiple patterns by adding in kernels in your convolution.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I will check it, and let you know.