# numpy where on a 2d or 3d dimension with multiple values

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find if `a3` contains `output_color`, and if so get index of where it is.

```
a3 = np.array([[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
                   9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
    
output_color = [1]
    
img = np.where(np.all(a3 == output_color, axis=0, keepdims=True))

print (img)
```

above code has no problem if its a single value

```
result
(array([0, 0], dtype=int64), array([0, 2], dtype=int64))
```

but how do I get the index with multiple values like

```
a3 = np.array([[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
               9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])

output_color = np.array([[1,2,1,2,3]])

img = np.where(np.all(a3 == output_color, axis=0, keepdims=True))
```

my desired result will be

```
result
array([0], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: The `where` is only as good as its boolean argument.  That in turn, depends on `a3 == output_color` or some variant.  `a3` is (9,2); `==` test with a (2,) produces (9,2) boolean.  But you can't do `==` with a (2,2); you'll get a broadcasting error.  If `a3` was (4,2,2) then you could do the comparison.

Comment: i think i miswrote the question, can you check again?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your desired output. As far as I understood you want to evaluate if some value exists once or several times in an array and return its indices, or something like that?

Comment: @DSteman if a3 has output_color's value in order. for example, if output_color has an array of [1,2,0,2,3], the result of np.where would be None because a3 doesnt have [,1,2,0,2,3] but it has [1,2,1,2,3]

Comment: And what should be the result when it does find a match?

Comment: (array([0], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64))

Comment: Duplicate of [Finding Patterns in a Numpy Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491979/finding-patterns-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: @flawr thank you sir, i'd been searching for this for a long time on stackoverflow! and you just saved me